# Combine $_FILES and $_POST into one AJAX call with Javascript only

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am having difficulty sending an ajax call that contains both a file and a string. I have no difficulty making either post or file, but not both together. I need this in pure Javascript, which i am more proficient than Jquery. 
here is the code i am working with...

```
    function uploadFile(){
var title = _('title').value;
var genere = _('genere').value;
var stars = _('stars').value;
var description = _('description').value;
    var file = _("video").files[0];
     //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata =  new FormData();
formdata.append("video", file);
formdata.append("title", title);
formdata.append("genere", genere);
formdata.append("stars", stars);
formdata.append("description", description);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "video_php/video_upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
```

This is the php.....

```
<?PHP
$fileName = '';
$fileTmpLoc = '';
$fileType = '';
$fileSize = '';
$title = '';
$genere = '';
$stars = '';
$description = '';
$retn=  '';
if (!isset($_FILES["video"]["name"])) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}else{
    $fileName       =   $_FILES["video"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc     =   $_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType       =   explode('.',$fileName); // The type of file it is
$fileType       =   end($fileType); // The end type of file it is
$fileSize       =   $_FILES["video"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$title = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9, ]#i', '', $_POST['title']);
$genere = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9, ]#i', '', $_POST['genere']);
$stars = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9, ]#i', '', $_POST['stars']);
$description = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9, ]#i', '', $_POST['description']);
}
echo $fileName.'<br/>';
echo $fileTmpLoc.'<br/>';
echo $fileType.'<br/>';
echo $fileSize.'<br/>';
echo $title.'<br/>';
echo $genere.'<br/>';
echo $description.'<br/>';
?>
```

I have been stuck on this for weeks. I have been through SO as well as many other sites with google. Every answer CLOSE to my desired result has been in Jquery. One solution i had was to make a 2-step form, uploading first one dataset, then the other, but i think both can be sent together for user usability. I have seen it done on several other websites.
NOTE* 
Above code has been corrected. Added

```
formdata.append("video", file);
formdata.append("title", title);
formdata.append("genere", genere);
formdata.append("stars", stars);
formdata.append("description", description);
```

It is now fully functional, thanks to @Ohgodwhy
Origional Question is at [Send $_POST and $_FILE data to php with JAVASCRIPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194591/send-post-and-file-data-to-php-with-javascript)

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax

Comment: hmm... why was this downvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the value of `_('title')` to be added to the `formdata`.

Given that you have this:

```
formdata.append("video", file);
```

All you need to do is this:

```
formdata.append('title', title);
```

The `FormData` object will handle the transmission of the file, and `title` will be available as `$_POST['title'];`

Comment: Worked like a CHARM !! TY very much